# How to install kio-ftps on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: krusader

I need FTPS protocol for Krusader and I've found that kio-ftps is solution.
But E: Unable to locate package kio-ftps appears on 20.10 version. What should I do to install FTPS protocol for Krusader?

Answer (score 0):

This addon is not available for Ubuntu, but you can compile it by following [PKGBUILD from ArchLinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=kf5-kio-ftps):

```
sudo apt-get install cmake extra-cmake-modules libkf5kio-dev libkf5kdelibs4support-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/Akimkin/kf5-kio-ftps/archive/v0.3.1.zip
unzip v0.3.1.zip
cd kf5-kio-ftps-0.3.1
cmake . -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-I/usr/include/KF5/KDELibs4Support $CXXFLAGS"
sudo make install
```

After this the `ftps://` will be listed in the *Tools* → *New Net Connection*.

Comment: `sftp` != `ftps`  FTPS is FTP + SSL - not SSH tunneled FTP.

Comment: Oh, my bad! It is night here. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

1. fix for annoying msgbox about self-signed server cert from novalu@ https://store.kde.org/p/1128347/
   // change in ftp.cpp:

```
      {
    if (messageBox(WarningContinueCancel, errors.at(i).errorString(), 
    "TLS Handshake Error", 
    QObject::tr("&Continue"),
    QObject::tr("&Cancel")) == KMessageBox::Cancel) doNotIgnore = false;
      }
```

to:

```
      {
//comment out if block to hide self-sig cert err msg
//  if (messageBox(WarningContinueCancel, errors.at(i).errorString(), 
//  "TLS Handshake Error", 
//  QObject::tr("&Continue"),
//  QObject::tr("&Cancel")) == KMessageBox::Cancel) 
doNotIgnore = false;
      }
```

2. unresolved: very slow speed e.g. 20+ seconds in Krusader listing small dir (filezilla on same is a couple seconds)
   changing below row (32 -> 31, 64, 128, 640) in ftp.cpp - no positive impact

```
  maximumIpcSize = 32 * 1024,
```